# Make two classes that are dependent on each other equatable

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have class A:

```
public class A : IEquatable<A>
{
    public B Owner { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as A);
    }

    public bool Equals([AllowNull] A other)
    {
        return other is A a &&
               EqualityComparer<B>.Default.Equals(Owner, a.Owner);
    }
}
```

And I have a class B:

```
public class B : IEquatable<B>
{
    public List<A> Children { get; set; } = new List<A>();

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as B);
    }

    public bool Equals([AllowNull] B other)
    {
        return other is B b &&
               EqualityComparer<List<A>>.Default.Equals(Children, b.Children);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is making `Equals()` methods of the above classes work. The `Equals()` methods in the example are generated by VS Code, but always return false in case of class B.

I also tried using LINQ expressions (such as SequenceEqual method), but it always results in Stack Overflow (because of circular dependency?).

As a side note, I used .NET Core 3.0 to run this.

Comment: You can write your own custom comparer for that. Btw, why do you need the circular reference here?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski for example a Product (A) and its Manufacturer (B). Manufacturer can have many Products, but product can only have one manufacturer, and they point at each other. As for custom comparer, I thought about that, just don't know how and can't find almost any info about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to find the answer to my question. I just implemented my own custom IEqualityComparer. (in the example below I added `public Guid ID` property to both classes to do proper `GetHashCode()`).

```
public class BComparer : IEqualityComparer<B>
{
    public bool Equals([AllowNull] B x, [AllowNull] B y)
    {
        if (x is null || y is null)  {return false;}

        if (x.ID == y.ID) {
            return x.Children.SequenceEqual(y.Children);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] B obj)
    {
        return obj.ID.ToString().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```